# Winforms in .NET Core 6.0 issue with VS 2022

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to add control to a Winforms application running on .NET Core 6.0 in VS 2022 Community edition. Whenever I add a control from the toolbox, like a button or a label, and try to save the project, an error message pops up

> Should have two or more class parts

There's no further information. Here's a screenshot or reference:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Report a problem with the Visual Studio product or installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) and [How to report a problem for Visual Studio and Visual Studio Installer](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/report)

Comment: Do you have a `Form1.Designer.cs` file under the `Form1.cs`?

Comment: @shingo Form1.Designer.cs is present

Comment: @user09938 tried scaling by restarting still the same result.

Comment: I feel that this error is popped by an extension, have you tried [safe mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2022)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case, the problem seems to be adding a second class in the form class file.

**Workaround**: Define the new class in another file.

Steps to reproduce the issue [Visual Studio 17.5.0 final]:

1. Create a new project:
   Template: `Windows Forms App` (C#). Next.
   Set project name (i.e. MyApplication). Next.
   Framework: .NET 6.0 (Long Term Support). Create.
2. (Visual Studio creates the project and opens Form1.cs in designer)
3. Add a button control to form. Save (Ctrl+S). Ok.
4. F7 to access form code.
5. Add a second class (i.e. MyClass) below Form1 class, in the same namespace:

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
      
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

6. Save (Ctrl+S). Ok.
7. Return to designer and change anything (i.e. move the button position).
8. Save (Ctrl+S) --> Error: “Should have two or more class parts”

Comment: thats a great catch, i had another class in same namespace, removed that resolves the issue. Thanks