# Changing the size of a window in Windows Forms gives "Should have two or more class paths." error

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2022, windows-forms-designer

Yesterday, I started getting the ***"Should have two or more class parts."*** error when I adjust my UI through the Windows Forms Designer.  This is on an established application.  I then created a quick Win Forms application with a single button used to test some computational code through the debugger.  I edit the code, execute the program, click the button, and use the debugger to walk through the code.  This works fine.  However, if I try to adjust the size of the button, or adjust the size of the Form1 window and try to Rebuild the application, I get the ***"Should have two or more class parts."*** error with no additional information.  When I look at the **Form1.Designer.cs** file it retains the original settings prior to the attempted adjustment of the UI.  If I close Visual Studio,  I have to agree to lose any changes to the project.  Upon reopening the Visual Studio project, my app runs fine, unless I try and change the UI in any way (adjust sizes, add controls, etc.).

I tried creating a new application in C# and the same error occurs.  This application is as close to "Hello World" in its simplicity.  I did note that yesterday Visual Studio was patched/upgraded.  I suspect that may have something to do with the issue suddenly appearing on new applications as well as older, well-established, applications.  I tried devenv /Safemode but that did not help.

Here is a section of my Designer.cs (below).  When I edited this file directly to add the BackColor for button1 and the size of Form1, then save the Designer.cs file, and execute the program, all works perfectly.  The error seems to be with the Windows Forms Designer.

I wanted to add the tag "net7.0-windows" but I don't have enough reputation points to do that and that tag has not yet been created.

```
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            button1 = new Button();
            SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            button1.Location = new Point(28, 18);
            button1.Name = "button1";
            button1.Size = new Size(314, 105);
            button1.TabIndex = 0;
            button1.Text = "Calculate Tables";
            button1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
            //button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            button1.Click += button1_Click;
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(7F, 15F);
            AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
            ClientSize = new Size(400, 200);
            Controls.Add(button1);
            Name = "Form1";
            Text = "Form1";
            ResumeLayout(false);
        }
```

Comment: _I did note that yesterday Visual Studio was patched/upgraded_:  If the issue occurred after an update, try repairing Visual Studio using the `Visual Studio Installer`. If that doesn't work, you may consider downgrading to a previous version that worked. The following may be useful: [Uninstall or remove Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Do the .Designer.cs file and the Form.cs file *both* define the class as *partial* ?

Comment: Are you related to @sansknwoledge? That person asked basically the same question yesterday. Your question is more detailed, but his/hers had an image of the error. My guess is it's a `partial` keyword missing somewhere, but that's just a guess. It's a particularly poor programmer experience that should be reported to MSFT

Comment: To user09938: Making assumptions often leads us to mistakes.  No, I do not have another ID.  I have used StackExchange for over a decade, but not submitted many questions and hence no reputation points.

Comment: I did try the Visual Studio Installer again without success.  My next attempt may be to completely remove Visual Studio and do a fresh install.

Comment: Both the Form1.cs and the Designer.cs have "partial class Form1 : Form"

Comment: @user1217123: Not an assumption, an educated guess based on the same observation as another commenter on a rather similar post by someone else yesterday. One doesn't need to ask questions to get points. If you click on my user ID you'll notice that I have zero points from asking questions - all my reputation points are from helping others. Over a decade? Interesting.

Comment: You may consider backing up (imaging) your computer before proceeding.

Comment: Here's the post of someone experiencing a rather similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75552766/winforms-in-net-core-6-0-issue-with-vs-2022 . You may consider working with him/her/them to see if you can find a solution.

Comment: @Flydog57 It is not the problem of missing 'partial' keyword. I have the same issue after the last update.

Comment: This issue is under investigation. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Show-There-should-be-two-or-more-class/10277235

Comment: @user09938 I searched for similar problems first, and found the question you cite, before posting my question.  The system requires you to have at least 50 reputation points to make a comment on another question and I had 3.  The only way, I saw, to participate was to post my question which gets me a voice in the conversation and 10 reputation points.  Posting an answer gains points, but I did not have the answer -- hence the question.  15 reputation points are required to "up-tick" a question to show interest in that question. Peace!  Can two users "chat" directly with each other?

Comment: @user1217123: You may consider using your _over a decade_ of experience to help others with issues that are of no direct benefit to you which may help you to earn reputation points. This indirectly benefits you because once you have enough points it allows you to comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems the same problem as reported in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75552766/winforms-in-net-core-6-0-issue-with-vs-2022). I posted a possible explanation and workaround. Copy-pasted here for visibility:

In my case, the problem seems to be adding a second class in the form class file.

**Workaround**: Define the new class in another file.

Steps to reproduce the issue [Visual Studio 17.5.0 final]:

1. Create a new project: Template: Windows Forms App (C#). Next. Set project name (i.e. MyApplication). Next. Framework: .NET 6.0 (Long Term Support). Create.
2. (Visual Studio creates the project and opens Form1.cs in designer)
3. Add a button control to form. Save (Ctrl+S).Ok.
4. F7 to access form code.
5. Add a second class (i.e. MyClass) below Form1 class, in the same
   namespace:

```
namespace MyApplication
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

6. Save (Ctrl+S). Ok.
7. Return to designer and change anything (i.e. move the button
   position).
8. Save (Ctrl+S) --> Error: “**Should have two or more class parts**”

Comment: I'll accept your answer as it is a good work around.  But there is an underlying problem in Visual Studio here and I'm glad to see it is under technical investigation.  The code being modified has been working fine with multiple classes in the same file for years and worked one day and then not the next day.

Comment: Looks like you can roll back your VS to a earlier build. First you have to uninstall everything then pick the fixed version bootstrappers you want. I am trying now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history

Comment: I'd like to report rolling back did solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple Classes in a form, I tried cutting the non-form related ones out, saving the file, then adding them back in again and saving.  Problem goes away till you moving anything on the form.