# Visual studio throwing errors after update

Tags: visual-studio

I updated my VS 2022 today...bad mistake thanks MS. Now I am getting errors when I try to run my project. First I get an error about "should have two or more class parts" then I get "unable to start debugger". Does anybody have any ideas as to why this could be happening?

[image]
[image]

I have tried deleting my CurrentSettings.vssettings file, and deleting my obj and bin folders. Not really sure what else to try.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75567897/changing-the-size-of-a-window-in-windows-forms-gives-should-have-two-or-more-cl

Comment: Thanks dr.null....This has got to be the worst edition of VS i've ever used...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a bug in the newest build of VS. 17.5+ and it has been reported to MS here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Show-There-should-be-two-or-more-class/10277235

I was able to temporarily fix the issue by completely uninstalling VS and then install one of the fixed version bootstrappers here (17.4.4 does not have the bug):
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-history

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It was because I had mistakenly set my form StartPosition position to CenterParent instead of CenterScreen